# MFC App Window Pop up

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to do a simple menu window in MFC. That as soon as the app is open, the app loads and on top of it a window pops up and displays 3 buttons to press. This is what i mean by menu window (I don't know if it has another name, excuse my lack of knowledge). I found some information about a modal window but I don't know how that works. I though about using a dialog box but I'm not sure if thats the correct way to go.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use a modal dialog, then go ahead and use a modal dialog. I don't understand the question.

Comment: @IInspectable what I mean is that for example if you open an app, the first thing that comes up is a dialog box with 3 buttons Play, Scores, Quit. Instead of the game itself. Then if you press play, it will continue to the app, if you press scores then it goes to another dialog box and if quit then the app closes completely.

Comment: Since you want to block input from reaching the main application, while the startup UI is displayed, you are looking for a modal solution. Since your startup UI hosts controls, a dialog is the standard choice. In essence, you want a modal dialog. See [About Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644994.aspx) for additional information. This is presented in terms of the Windows API. MFC is built on top of the Windows API, and the concepts are the same.